# Devise sign_in method wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

When I try to use the sign_in or sign_in_with_redirect I've been getting wrong number of arguments (1 for 0).

We're using rails 4.2, ruby 2.2.0, devise 3.4.1 and the code looks like:

```
  #find an authentication account
  card = Card::Dog.where(id: ##)

  #get card associated with the dog account
  @user = card.user

  #sign in card
  sign_in @user
```

I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong as it all seems pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess the code you posted is in your controller. Is it possible that you have a `sign_in` action in the same controller too?

If that is true, then that controller action (that takes no arguments) overrides devise's `sign_in` method (that expects arguments). Rename your `sign_in` controller method (and the routes and links to that method) to something like `log_in` instead.

Comment: Ah, this was it!  Too many hours of looking at code, I thought I was going crazy.  Thank you!

Comment: This was the case for me too.  I was defining a "sign_in" action in my ActiveAdmin controller.  Changing the action name to "log_in" fixed it.

Comment: I was using the `devise_token_auth` gem and had included in the application controller this line: `include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken` - which confused my views because the same methods are available to them - but with different parameters!